# How Angular routing works on github pages

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, github-pages, angular2-directives

I am running a angular app on github pages.

I read somewhere that it will not support dynamic features of angular.
Like directives and routing.

But routing is working fine of me.
How is it possible?

I have deployed dist after doing ng build.

Also, can anyone explain how directives are dynamic?

Thanks

Comment: Have you created a copy of the index.html and renamed it to 404.html. The routing would work if you did this step. https://angular.io/guide/deployment#:~:text=When%20the%20build%20is%20complete%2C%20make%20a%20copy%20of%20docs/index.html%20and%20name%20it%20docs/404.html.

Comment: Yeah..i did that. What about directives?

Comment: Directives should work on Github Pages. Isn't is working for you? Which directives specifically are you talking about?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [William](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2178360) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69380522) saying "Try switching to Hash based location strategy [https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy)"